# Signature Verification failed while transfering sol NFT

Tags: web3.js, spl-token

```
import * as web3 from "@solana/web3.js";
import { Token, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from "@solana/spl-token";

async function transfer(tokenMintAddress: string, to: string) {
  const connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

  let secretKey = Uint8Array.from([
    125, 135,  39,  61, 138, 119,   8, 142,  92,  59, 250,
    54,  33,  15, 138, 244, 240, 191, 205, 118,   8,   8,
    .....
    222, 194, 197,  36,  27, 150, 252, 186, 189
  ]);
  
  const wallet = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);

  const mintPublicKey = new web3.PublicKey(tokenMintAddress);
 
  const mintToken = new Token(
    connection,
    mintPublicKey,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    wallet // the wallet owner will pay to transfer and to create recipients associated token account if it does not yet exist.
  );

  console.log(mintToken);

  const fromTokenAccount = await mintToken.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(
    wallet.publicKey
  );

  console.log("fromTokenAccount",fromTokenAccount);

  const destPublicKey = new web3.PublicKey(to);

  // Get the derived address of the destination wallet which will hold the custom token
  const associatedDestinationTokenAddr = await Token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    mintToken.associatedProgramId,
    mintToken.programId,
    mintPublicKey,
    destPublicKey
  );


  console.log('associatedDestinationTokenAddr:::: ', associatedDestinationTokenAddr);

  const receiverAccount = await connection.getAccountInfo(
    associatedDestinationTokenAddr
  );

  console.log('receiverAccount::: ', receiverAccount)
  const instructions: web3.TransactionInstruction[] = [];

  if (receiverAccount === null) {
    instructions.push(
      Token.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        mintToken.associatedProgramId,
        mintToken.programId,
        mintPublicKey,
        associatedDestinationTokenAddr,
        destPublicKey,
        wallet.publicKey
      )
    );
  }

  instructions.push(
    Token.createTransferInstruction(
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      fromTokenAccount.address,
      associatedDestinationTokenAddr,
      wallet.publicKey,
      [],
      1,
    )
  );

  const transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(...instructions);
  
  transaction.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;
  
  transaction.recentBlockhash = (
    await connection.getLatestBlockhash()
  ).blockhash;


  const transactionSignature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(
    transaction.serialize(),
    {skipPreflight: true,preflightCommitment: 'confirmed',}
  );

  console.log("transactionSignature:::  ",transactionSignature);

  const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

  await connection.confirmTransaction( 
    transactionSignature);
}
```

This is my code to transfer SOL nft using spl token library. Its giving me following error:

```
  throw new Error('Signature verification failed');
        ^
```

Error: Signature verification failed

Comment: Makes sense, you're not signing the transaction before sending it off - try [`transaction.sign([wallet])`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Transaction.html#sign)

Answer (score 1):

solved the issue using token.sendandConfirmtransaction(params here)